# How to import data into neo4j (neo4j-community-2.0.0) in windows 7?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient, node-neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I got the below link to do this but the problem is that it's for linux users !!!

http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/03/importing-data-into-neo4j-spreadsheet.html

Please help me to get this done on windows ? Thanks in advance.

I am new to neo4j and got only a little hands on experience on java.

---

I added neo4jtools to my neo4j server from the below link

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools

then I follow this command to import few data to a graph database

```
neo4jshell -path C:\Program Files\neo4j-community-2.0.0\data\test5.db -config C:\Program Files\neo4j-community-2.0.0\conf\neo4j.properties -file C:\Users\admin\Downloads\import.txt
```

and I get a message like this on the command prompt

```
> Transaction started
> +-------------------+ | No data returned. |
> +-------------------+ Nodes created: 20 Properties set: 60 3586 ms Transaction committed Transaction started ERROR (-v for expanded
> information):
>         MissingIndexException: Index `node_auto_index` does not exist
```

my import.txt file contents are these

```
BEGIN

create ({id:'1', name:'Amada Emory', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'2', name:'Rana Seely', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'3', name:'Detra Thatcher', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'4', name:'Melda Reza', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'5', name:'Shana Willems', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'6', name:'Sharonda Peele', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'7', name:'Dagny Agee', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'8', name:'Tisa Woodman', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'9', name:'Shelba Mutchler', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'10', name:'Anderson Spagnola', type:'Male'})
create ({id:'11', name:'Pamala Forward', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'12', name:'Melva Fairchild', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'13', name:'Antione Selman', type:'Male'})
create ({id:'14', name:'Carmelia Cali', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'15', name:'Fairy Daughtery', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'16', name:'Stefany Mcamis', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'17', name:'Kermit Meaney', type:'Male'})
create ({id:'18', name:'Williemae Dossantos', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'19', name:'Marth Sparling', type:'Female'})
create ({id:'20', name:'Jarvis Noland', type:'Male'});

COMMIT

BEGIN

start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='1'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='11') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='1'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='12') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='1'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='13') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='2'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='14') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='2'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='15') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='2'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='16') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='3'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='17') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='3'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='18') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='3'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='19') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='10'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='20') create n1-[:FATHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='14'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='1') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='11'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='2') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='11'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='3') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='12'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='4') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='12'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='5') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='12'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='6') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='17'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='7') create n1-[:FATHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='13'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='8') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='13'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='9') create n1-[:MOTHER_OF]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='20'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='1') create n1-[:FATHER_OF]->n2;

COMMIT

EXIT
```

And I can see lot of thing are created inside the test5.db folder,

but when I go to my browser console I cant see any nodes there ?

Is there anything more to do ? Am on the right way ? Please help me to move on !!!

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

My ne04j.properties contents are

```
# Default values for the low-level graph engine
#neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=25M
#neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=50M
#neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=90M
#neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=130M
#neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M

# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version
#allow_store_upgrade=true

# Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
#cypher_parser_version=2.0

# Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for
# legacy reasons To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such
# as: "7 days" or "100M size" instead of "true" keep_logical_logs=true

# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#node_keys_indexable=name,age node_keys_indexable=id,name,type


# Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false relationship_auto_indexing=true

# The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#relationship_keys_indexable=name,age relationship_keys_indexable=id,name,type,age

# location of the database directory  org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/test5.db
```

and neo4j-server.properties are here

```
################################################################
# Neo4j configuration
#
################################################################

#***************************************************************
# Server configuration
#***************************************************************

# location of the database directory  org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/test7.db

# Let the webserver only listen on the specified IP. Default is localhost (only
# accept local connections). Uncomment to allow any connection. Please see the
# security section in the neo4j manual before modifying this.
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0

#
# HTTP Connector
#

# http port (for all data, administrative, and UI access) org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474

#
# HTTPS Connector
#

# Turn https-support on/off org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true

# https port (for all data, administrative, and UI access) org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473

# Certificate location (auto generated if the file does not exist) org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.cert

# Private key location (auto generated if the file does not exist) org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.key

# Internally generated keystore (don't try to put your own
# keystore there, it will get deleted when the server starts) org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.keystore.location=data/keystore

#*****************************************************************
# Administration client configuration
#*****************************************************************

# location of the servers round-robin database directory. Possible values:
# - absolute path like /var/rrd
# - path relative to the server working directory like data/rrd
# - commented out, will default to the database data directory. org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rrdb.location=data/rrd

# REST endpoint for the data API
# Note the / in the end is mandatory org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=/db/data/

# REST endpoint of the administration API (used by Webadmin) org.neo4j.server.webadmin.management.uri=/db/manage/

# Low-level graph engine tuning file org.neo4j.server.db.tuning.properties=conf/neo4j.properties

# The console services to be enabled org.neo4j.server.manage.console_engines=shell


# Comma separated list of JAX-RS packages containing JAX-RS resources, one
# package name for each mountpoint. The listed package names will be loaded
# under the mountpoints specified. Uncomment this line to mount the
# org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged.HelloWorldResource.java from
# neo4j-examples under /examples/unmanaged, resulting in a final URL of
# `http://localhost:7474/examples/unmanaged/helloworld/{nodeId}`
#org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged


#*****************************************************************
# HTTP logging configuration
#*****************************************************************

# HTTP logging is disabled. HTTP logging can be enabled by setting this
# property to 'true'. org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=false

# Logging policy file that governs how HTTP log output is presented and
# archived. Note: changing the rollover and retention policy is sensible, but
# changing the output format is less so, since it is configured to use the
# ubiquitous common log format org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml
```

Comment: You removed the `#` to enable auto indexing, but then you removed the line break too so `node_auto_indexing=true` is not on its own line. Put it back on its own line. Then remove the `#` before the `node_keys_indexable` and choose which keys to index. Just make your config look like the snippet from Michaels answer.

Answer (score 3):

What does your config look like?

Do you have auto-indexing enabled like this:

```
# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
node_keys_indexable=id,name,type
```

Remove the hashes and make sure that the `id` property is listed. You might or might not add the `name` and `type` properties for index lookups as well.

Also you don't see anything in your browser because you created `data/test5.db` but the server is by default looking for `data/graph.db`.

1. So either use this directory.
2. Or start the server, and then leave off the `-path` parameter and the shell will connect to your running server.

Comment: it is already enabled in the neo4j.properties file I also added a line # location of the database directory 
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/test5.db this is also included in the  neo4j-server.properties file too. So while I open the browser I can read the location of Database

Location:
C:\Program Files\neo4j-community-2.0.0\data\test5.db
Size:
141.87 KiB @Michael Hunger

Answer (score 2):

your final goal is to import the sheet.So follow the steps given in link provided by you and put the cypher queries in a file.Then use java code to read file([BufferReader](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)) and run the cypher queries using  ExecutionEngine.

While copying queries don't forget to put any separator which will recognize  the start and end of cypher queries.Run queries in loop.

Comment: I had updated my question @Punendu , could you please provide me with any link ?

Comment: As your error says you have not enabled auto indexing.first enable that by changing in conf/neo4j.properties.

Comment: # Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
node_auto_indexing=true this is put in my properties file @Purnendu

Comment: I think that is not created because of MissingIndexException.By default node_auto_indexing=true is commented .check if it is commented then uncomment it.

Comment: its enabled node_auto_indexing=true the hash mark is removed from the beginig, I can see lot of files inside the database folder but unfortunately zero node returning in the browser !!! @Purnendu

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to import data from other source into Neo4j, you can use ETL Software like Talend.
Here is a step by step post shows how to that in a simple way:
[Import Data into Neo4j directly using Talend](http://lucidwebdreams.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/import-data-into-neo4j-from-ms-sql-server-directly-using-talend/).
It shows how to import data from MS SQL Sever but you can easily change the source