# How to create relation between nodes grouped under labels in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient, node-neo4j

I had created two group of nodes in graph using the following cypher query

pharma group

```
CREATE ( p1:pharma { name: " Magnesium ", id: " 12 " } ) 
CREATE ( p2:pharma { name: " Hyoscine Butylbromide ", id: " 22 " } ) 
CREATE ( p3:pharma { name: " Propantheline Bromide ", id: " 23 ",  } );
```

ind group

```
CREATE ( i1:ind { id: '1', name: 'Dyspepsia',  pdfk: '12'}) 
CREATE ( i2:ind { id: '5', name: 'Symptomic relief of intestinal disorder', pdfk: '22'}) 
CREATE ( i3:ind { id: '6', name: 'Symptomic relief of disorder', pdfk: '22'}) 
CREATE ( i4:ind { id: '7', name: 'Bowel colic', review: 'False', pdfk: '23'});
```

its just like relational database tabels, Now I want to define relation ship between these two group of nodes..

relationship like = node in pharma with id 12 has a relationship name HAS_IND with node in ind with id 1 ?

somewhere like this

```
MATCH (a:pharma),(b:ind)
WHERE a.id = '12' AND b.id = '1'
CREATE (a)-[:has_ind]->(b);
```

I tried these too

```
MATCH (a:pharmaDrug),(b:indication)
WHERE a.name = 'Magnesium Carbonate' AND b.name = 'Dyspepsia'
CREATE (a)-[:has_indication]->(b);
```

but both are giving **Returned 0 rows in 530 ms** in the console ?

Please help me to find the correct cypher query for this purpose. Thanks in advance.

========================================================================

My changes are as follows

```
CREATE ( p1:pharma { name: "Magnesium", id: 12 } ) 
CREATE ( p2:pharma { name: "Hyoscine Butylbromide", id: 22 } ) 
CREATE ( p3:pharma { name: "Propantheline Bromide", id: 23 } );




CREATE ( i1:ind { id: 1, name: 'Dyspepsia',  pdfk: '12'}) 
CREATE ( i2:ind { id: 5, name: 'Symptomic relief of intestinal disorder', pdfk: '22'}) 
CREATE ( i3:ind { id: 6, name: 'Symptomic relief of disorder', pdfk: '22'}) 
CREATE ( i4:ind { id: 7, name: 'Bowel colic', review: 'False', pdfk: '23'});
```

this create nodes under two labels

```
MATCH (a:pharma),(b:ind)
WHERE a.id = ' 12 ' AND b.id = ' 1 '
CREATE (a)-[:has_indication]->(b);
```

this give zero rows affected with no output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the way you've created your items, if you look at your 'pharma' code you have:

```
CREATE ( p1:pharma { name: " Magnesium ", id: " 12 " } )
```

To match against this you need to do:

```
MATCH (a:pharma) 
WHERE a.id = ' 12 '
RETURN a
```

I've added extra spaces around the '12' to get it to match. So you're query would read as:

```
MATCH (a:pharma),(b:ind)
WHERE a.id = ' 12 ' AND b.id = '1'
CREATE (a)-[:has_indication]->(b)
```

Now, that'll get it to work - but it might be worth changing your model a bit, if the `id` is always an integer, I would change your creates to being:

```
CREATE ( p1:pharma { name: "Magnesium", id: 12 } ) 
CREATE ( p2:pharma { name: "Hyoscine Butylbromide", id: 22 } ) 
CREATE ( p3:pharma { name: "Propantheline Bromide", id: 23 } );
```

and be **SUPER** careful with your use of the `"` (or `'`) character, in your original creates you are adding extra spaces for the names as well (which is why your second query didn't work)

**EDIT**

OK, this is a fully working set of data, I've edited both of your create statements to get this:

```
CREATE ( p1:pharma { name: 'Magnesium', id: 12 } ) 
CREATE ( p2:pharma { name: 'Hyoscine Butylbromide', id: 22 } ) 
CREATE ( p3:pharma { name: 'Propantheline Bromide', id: 23} )
CREATE ( i1:ind { id: 1, name: 'Dyspepsia',  pdfk: 12}) 
CREATE ( i2:ind { id: 5, name: 'Symptomic relief of intestinal disorder', pdfk: 22}) 
CREATE ( i3:ind { id: 6, name: 'Symptomic relief of disorder', pdfk: 22}) 
CREATE ( i4:ind { id: 7, name: 'Bowel colic', review: 'False', pdfk: 23})
```

Basically I've removed the `'` characters and used integers for id (and pdfk).
The `MATCH` for this is:

```
MATCH (a:pharma),(b:ind)
WHERE a.id = 12 AND b.id = 1
CREATE (a)-[:has_ind]->(b)
```

And to check it works (aside from the message you get back):

```
MATCH (p:pharma),(i:ind) RETURN p,i
```

You'll see one is linked to another.

Comment: I had recreated another graph database and also remodelled my cypher query with single quote (removed double quotes) also removed quotes for integer values. Then I run the cypher to create relation as you mentioned above, i get the same - Returned 0 rows in 702 ms ? Is there any thing to be done on properties files (auto-indexing is set to true) I have been trying this for the last couple of days and idn't found any break through... @Chris Skardon

Comment: I had tried the tutorials in neo4j site (node created with no labels) and defining relationship with start syntax with node autoindexing it is working but my relations are not working !! Is there any thing like this I can do ? ( start n=node(12), m=node(1) create n<-[:HASIND]->m; ) ....

Comment: Without the new `create` statements and the `match` it's difficult to say what you're changes require... Maybe you could add them to your question?

Comment: I've added an example which will *hopefully* help

Comment: ok let me check , and thank you for the quick response (helps) @Chris Skardon

Comment: thank you very much !! its working One more thing, how can we create multiple relationship, I mean for other id's ? @Chris Skardon

Comment: this is also working ( start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='12'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='1') create n1-[:HAS_IND]->n2; ) so which is good to use in development ? @Chris Skardon Once agin Thank you very much for the wonderful help -:))

Comment: Well, those are really separate questions, you want to avoid any queries using `START` as that's older syntax. I would just use the `MATCH` clause you originally had. Multiple relationships would need to be another question - no answer would be formatted correctly in the comments, and what you want to do is unclear.

Comment: thank you @Chris Skardon Please check this link ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986962/how-to-import-data-into-neo4j-neo4j-community-2-0-0-in-windows-7?rq=1 )